# Pictures of trigger point muscle fascia

Tags: muscles

Are there any pictures of an actual trigger point looks like? All I am able to find online are animations.

Comment: I found plenty of pictures of therapists conducting trigger point therapy on their patients. Are you looking for a picture of the actual trigger point picture underneath the skin?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: You can use @TheLastWord in your comment such that your comment will be seen in the inbox of the tagged user.

Comment: @TheLastWord Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have easily find these using a simple google search, however I will point several out:

- See figure 1 of [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4556911/) for an ultrasound image of a trigger point. Really interesting!
- See figure 1 of [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4508225/) for a schematic representation, and figure 2 for a real image. Although you did not ask for a deeper understanding of this topic, if you want to read more about it I would recommend reading this paper as it covers a lot of aspects (such as pain signals to the brain).
- [This article](https://www.archives-pmr.org/article/S0003-9993(09)00393-1/pdf) covers different imaging techniques and facilitates interpretation by using arrows to point out the trigger points.

If this is not what you are looking for **please specify** what you mean with "pictures"? (vibration sonoelastography, schematic, ultrasound, etc.) I cannot point you in a direction for real life images (if these even exist).

Comment: This is so insightful. Thanks for aggregating all of the info in this answer.